# How to implement Dijkstra's algorithm on dynamic data(input file) in place of static data in python?

Tags: python, file-io, dijkstra, shortest-path

The code to find shortest path between two nodes of a graph:

```
    import heapq
    import sys

    class Graph:

def __init__(self):
    self.vertices = {}

def add_vertex(self, name, edges):
    self.vertices[name] = edges

def shortest_path(self, start, finish):
    distances = {} # Distance from start to node
    previous = {}  # Previous node in optimal path from source
    nodes = [] # Priority queue of all nodes in Graph

    for vertex in self.vertices:
        if vertex == start: # Set root node as distance of 0
            distances[vertex] = 0
            heapq.heappush(nodes, [0, vertex])
        else:
            distances[vertex] = sys.maxint
            heapq.heappush(nodes, [sys.maxint, vertex])
        previous[vertex] = None

    while nodes:
        smallest = heapq.heappop(nodes)[1] # Vertex in nodes with smallest distance in distances
        if smallest == finish: # If the closest node is our target we're done so print the path
            path = []
            while previous[smallest]: # Traverse through nodes til we reach the root which is 0
                path.append(smallest)
                smallest = previous[smallest]
            return path
        if distances[smallest] == sys.maxint: # All remaining vertices are inaccessible from source
            break

        for neighbor in self.vertices[smallest]: # Look at all the nodes that this vertex is attached to
            alt = distances[smallest] + self.vertices[smallest][neighbor] # Alternative path distance
            if alt < distances[neighbor]: # If there is a new shortest path update our priority queue (relax)
                distances[neighbor] = alt
                previous[neighbor] = smallest
                for n in nodes:
                    if n[1] == neighbor:
                        n[0] = alt
                        break
                heapq.heapify(nodes)
    return distances

def __str__(self):
    return str(self.vertices)

g = Graph()
g.add_vertex('A', {'B': 7, 'C': 8})
g.add_vertex('B', {'A': 7, 'F': 2})
g.add_vertex('C', {'A': 8, 'F': 6, 'G': 4})
g.add_vertex('D', {'F': 8})
g.add_vertex('E', {'H': 1})
g.add_vertex('F', {'B': 2, 'C': 6, 'D': 8, 'G': 9, 'H': 3})
g.add_vertex('G', {'C': 4, 'F': 9}) 
g.add_vertex('H', {'E': 1, 'F': 3})
print g.shortest_path('A', 'F')
>>>['F','B']
```

Now I have an input file like :

```
London Birmingham 117
Birmingham Bristol 85
London Oxford 56
San_Francisco San_Jose 50
San_Jose Davis 270
San_Francisco Davis 350
END OF INPUT
```

So I tried using code like in place of the list in the end :

```
filename = open('Input1.txt', 'r')
for line in filename:

node1, node2, d = line.split()
if node1!="END" and node2!="OF"
    print node1,node2,d
    g.add_vertex(node1,{node2:d})
    g.add_vertex(node2,{node1:d})
```

But I am getting integer error, maybe because I am not able to map the distance.So please tell me what changes I should do to get the code working for the input file and to print the distances along with the vertices.

Comment: can you please post the exact error you are getting?

Comment: Not getting an error but output is like {'London':2147483647, 'Oxford':2147483647,.....}

Answer (score 0):

```
def add_vertex(self, name, edges):
    if name not in self.vertices:
        self.vertices[name] = edges
    else:
        self.vertices[name][list(edges)[0]] = edges[list(edges)[0]]
```

This is a work around. It is highly dependent upon the format of input via file that you gave. 
Also, note that after splitting you have to convert the distance (`d`) into `int`,

```
g.add_vertex(node1,{node2:int(d)})
g.add_vertex(node2,{node1:int(d)})
```

Here is the full code:

```
import heapq
import sys

class Graph:

    def __init__(self):
        self.vertices = {}

    def add_vertex(self, name, edges):
        if name not in self.vertices:
            self.vertices[name] = edges
        else:
            self.vertices[name][list(edges)[0]] = edges[list(edges)[0]]

    def shortest_path(self, start, finish):
        distances = {} # Distance from start to node
        previous = {}  # Previous node in optimal path from source
        nodes = [] # Priority queue of all nodes in Graph

        for vertex in self.vertices:
            if vertex == start: # Set root node as distance of 0
                distances[vertex] = 0
                heapq.heappush(nodes, [0, vertex])
            else:
                distances[vertex] = sys.maxint
                heapq.heappush(nodes, [sys.maxint, vertex])
            previous[vertex] = None

        while nodes:
            smallest = heapq.heappop(nodes)[1] # Vertex in nodes with smallest distance in distances
            if smallest == finish: # If the closest node is our target we're done so print the path
                path = []
                while previous[smallest]: # Traverse through nodes til we reach the root which is 0
                    path.append(smallest)
                    smallest = previous[smallest]
                return path
            if distances[smallest] == sys.maxint: # All remaining vertices are inaccessible from source
                break

            for neighbor in self.vertices[smallest]: # Look at all the nodes that this vertex is attached to
                alt = distances[smallest] + self.vertices[smallest][neighbor] # Alternative path distance
                if alt < distances[neighbor]: # If there is a new shortest path update our priority queue (relax)
                    distances[neighbor] = alt
                    previous[neighbor] = smallest
                    for n in nodes:
                        if n[1] == neighbor:
                            n[0] = alt
                            break
                    heapq.heapify(nodes)
        return distances

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.vertices)


g = Graph()
g.add_vertex('A', {'B': 7, 'C': 8})
g.add_vertex('B', {'A': 7, 'F': 2})
g.add_vertex('C', {'A': 8, 'F': 6, 'G': 4})
g.add_vertex('D', {'F': 8})
g.add_vertex('E', {'H': 1})
g.add_vertex('F', {'B': 2, 'C': 6, 'D': 8, 'G': 9, 'H': 3})
g.add_vertex('G', {'C': 4, 'F': 9}) 
g.add_vertex('H', {'E': 1, 'F': 3})
filename = open('input.txt', 'r')
print g.shortest_path('A', 'E')
for line in filename:
    node1, node2, d = line.split()
    if node1!="END" and node2!="OF":
        #print {node2: int(d)}
        g.add_vertex(node1,{node2:int(d)})
        g.add_vertex(node2,{node1:int(d)})

print g.shortest_path('London', 'E')
print g.shortest_path('A', 'E')
```

Comment: Got it...Thanks a lot! Could you pls tell what modification to do it I want the total shortest distance from   one node to another? For London, Bristol, getting output  ['Bristol', 'Birmingham']....I want total distance from London to Bristol which is 202.

Comment: It is just iterating over and adding the cost. I think it would be good if you try yourself. If any problem occurs there, then ask for help.